# How to translate 'para entusiasmar ' into English?

Tags: significado

What would "para entusiasmar" be in English? To be excited? To excite?

Sentence:

> Fitbit ha encontrado por fin el camino correcto **para entusiasmar** con un smartwatch.

Comment: Note that the question, as is, would fit better in [ell.se] or [elu.se]. However, you can tweak it a bit by asking _what does 'para entusiasmar' mean in Spanish_ so it is entirely on topic :) Welcome to the site, by the way!

Comment: ... to wow you with ....

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the suggested terms here:

[entusiasmar](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=entusiasmar)

- excite
- fill [sb] with excitement

In this case, it's possible to say that:

> Fitbit found the right way to fill (the public) with excitement with a smartwatch.